# $A$ and $B$ are infinite sets with $B \subseteq A$. Which of the following statements are true?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

> $A$ and $B$ are infinite sets with $B \subseteq A$. Which of the following statements are true?
>
> 1. $A \sim B$
> 2. $A \sim A \setminus B$
> 3. If $B$ is countable then $A \sim B$
> 4. If $A$ is countable then $A \sim B$
> 5. $A \setminus B$ is finite

**My Attempt:**

1. False: $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ but $\mathbb{N} \not\sim \mathbb{R} \implies \mathbb{R} \not\sim \mathbb{N}$
2. 
3. False: $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. $\mathbb{N}$ is countable but $\mathbb{N} \not\sim \mathbb{R} \implies \mathbb{R} \not\sim \mathbb{N}$
4. True: $B \subseteq A$ and $A$ countable $\implies B$ countable $\implies A \sim \mathbb{N}, B \sim \mathbb{N} \implies A \sim B$.
5. False: $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, but $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ is infinite.

Are these correct? Also, I am unsure about Question 2. Can someone please help point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean with $A \sim B$? Please try to be specific when using symbols that have different meanings depending on the context.

Comment: For 2, $A=B=\mathbb{N}$

Comment: $A \sim B$ denotes that $A$ is equivalent to $B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. As for (2)...

**HINT:** What happens if $A=B$?

Comment: If $A = B$ then $A \setminus B = \emptyset$. Thus $A \not\sim A \setminus B = \emptyset$ since we (clearly) cannot find a bijective function that maps $A$ to $A \setminus B = \emptyset$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.